# How can I filter out files with 1GB or more with Date Range .

Tags: linux, scripting

Can anyone suggest me script or command to find out the file with size more than 1 GB with date range like May 01 to May 31 .

Please help me to create the script or command . 
I want to move all files fall under date range May 01 to May 31 which is more than 1GB of Size.

Regards, 
Biswajit

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
touch --date "2017-05-01" /tmp/start
touch --date "2017-05-31" /tmp/end
find /path/ -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end -size +1G -exec mv "{}" /path/to/new/dir/ \;
```

you can use it as a bash script (e.g. `scriptname.sh /path/to/search/dir /path/to/destination/dir`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch --date "2017-05-01" /tmp/start
touch --date "2017-05-31" /tmp/end
find "$1" -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end -size +1G -exec mv "{}" "$2" \;
rm /tmp/start /tmp/end
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort . I will check and try . But I want a script that can be used for moving files .

Comment: @BiswajitSarkar: I updated the answer to move files to new location

Comment: The `exec mv "{}" /path/to/new/dir/ \;` does the move of the files that match the date criteria to the directory `/path/to/new/dir/`